# Como alterar apenas os checkboxes visíveis de uma datatable?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, java-ee-6

Situação problema, suponha que tenhamos um datatable no primefaces com as seguintes características:

- A primeira coluna ao invés do título tem um checkbox com o label *todos*.
- Todas as linhas, nesta primeira coluna, também tem um checkbox (e este checkbox se relacionada a um atributo da classe que está sendo usada para popular a tabela. Por exemplo, se forem carros, além da classe ter o nome e o valor do carro, por exemplo, também teria um campo *seleção*, que indicaria que aquele carro está selecionado ou não, atrelado a uma proprieade da classe que está sendo usada para popular a tabela.)
- Todas as colunas, exceto a primeira, tem um filtro *contains* para filtrar resultados.
- A tabela pode apresentar várias páginas.

Qual seria o jeito mais fácil e eficaz de fazer com que ao apertar o checkbox *todos*, apenas os checkboxes visíveis (ou seja, aqueles da página atual, já aplicando os filtros ou não) sejam selecionados (e por conseguinte também a sua propriedade de seleção no bean correspondente)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como você colocou a tag primfaces, suponho que o esteja usando. No próprio demo do primefaces tem o que você está perguntando.

Procure pela tabela que está usando checkbox e veja.

[Primefaces DataTable](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/selection.xhtml)

Comment: Nossa. Muito legal. Eu não tinha encontrado esse showcase. Obrigado.